# Hide photos & videos from the gallery

Tags: gallery, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

no matter what is stored on the Android operating system as long as there is no root rights needed to view this photo / video file stores in my case Amazon photos.

All photos & videos of the file system in your app or the pictures are released. But I do not want my photos and videos I automatically enter the gallery in another place like downloads / documents.

Unfortunately, I always have to go manually in the Amazon Photos app and hide the pictures that do not come from the camera which time unnecessarily wasted.

---

EDIT: After the hint of the community bot in the comments, I'll try to make the question simpler.

No matter where I save photos and videos on my device, for example in the music folder or in the documents folder, they end up in my photo gallery.

But I don't want them to get into my gallery because the pictures are in the documents folder and not in the camera folder.  What exactly can i do now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting the pictures or videos you don't want in the Gallery in your "Secure Folder"'s Gallery.

If you don't know, there is an app called Secure Folder and you can access several apps, including the Gallery app, and so the Secure Folder acts as like a private room with an additional body guard /  password required to enter.

You can move all pictures and videos in your Gallery to your Secure Folder Gallery by going to a specific pic/video, pressing the 3 vertical dots that appear in the lower right corner, and then tapping Move to Secure Folder, they will then disappear from the Gallery[image]

Comment: Secure Folder is specific to Samsung.  Although there may be similar apps on other makes of phone.